# How do you translate "hype" and "hyped"?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you translate *hype* and *hyped*? Such as in the sentences:

> Hype! The Duolingo course for Spanish speakers is out!
>
> I am so hyped!

Comment: This is a different kind of "hyped".

Answer (score 4):

Mi estas vigligata = I am energized